# ASP.NET event logging, file not created

Tags: json, .net

I am trying to setup an event logger for my ASP.net application. I have the appsetting.json file setup in the following way.

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    },
    "FilePath": "Logs//event.log"
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

I am looking for event.log when I run the application (which I try to crash so that information will be processed. I cannot find this event.log file. Have I overlooked something?